# SQL Server messes views code formatting on save

Tags: sql-server, formatting

Every time I save a view on SQL server such as:

```
SELECT column1
     , column2
FROM table1
WHERE column3 IN
(
    SELECT TOP(1) column4
    FROM table2
    INNER JOIN table3
    ON table2.column1 = table3.column1
)
```

SQL Server removes all my indenting, line breaks and tabs and creates a block such as this one:

```
SELECT column1 , column2
FROM table1
WHERE column3 IN (SELECT TOP(1) column4
    FROM table2 INNER JOIN table3
    ON table2.column1 = table3.column1)
```

This is ok for small queries, but makes long ones totaly unreadable. I know this is the default behavior for SQL Server but I haven't been able to find a setting to change formatting or disable it altogether. Is there a way to make SQL NOT change my code format upon saving?

Answer (score 0):

I always use scripts instead of the designer.  Either create view or alter view and my formatting is always preserved.

In SSMS you can right click view-> script view as-> alter to -> New query window

Comment: I get the same crappy condensed formatting when I do it this way as well.